# Power of sums estimates

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently asking myself if 
$(\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|)^q\leq K_q\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|^q$ holds for any $q\geq 0$, where $K_q$ is some constant depending on $q$.

If $q\geq 2$, the above holds by Jensen's inequality, since $f(x)=x^q$ is convex, if $q\geq 2$. Now the questions remains for the cases $0\leq q\leq 2$.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N \in \mathbb N$ and look at the sequence $a_n = 1$ if $n \le N$ and $a_n = 0$ if $n > N$.

$$\sum_n |a_n| = N\quad \text{and} \quad  \sum_n |a_n|^q = N.$$

Is there a constant $K_q$ satisfying $N^q \le K_q N$ for all $N$? Not if $q > 1$.

Comment: I am sorry for me not being clear..what I meant was $(\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|)^q\leq K_q\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|^q$

Comment: If your constant $K$ depends on $q$ but not on $n$ the answer gives you a counterexample. Do you mean $K_{n,q}$?